# Join infinite distributive (mathematical)

Tags: математика, фраза, терминология

Math term [join infinite distributive](https://planetmath.org/joininfinitedistributive) in Russian?

Also "meet infinite distributive"?

Comment: I decided to invent my own translation. Is it better "верхне дистрибутивная решетка" или "решетка дистрибутивная относительно супремумов"?

Comment: Perhaps you want a hyphen in the first option: верхне-дистрибутивная.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the term but comparing the definitions you linked and [Блюмин С.Л 2.4 (17) and (18)](http://edu.sernam.ru/book_mmn.php?id=20), looks like the translations are:

> infinite distributive - **бесконечно дистрибутивная**
>   join-infinite distributive - **брауэрова**
>   meet-infinite distributive **дуальная брауэрова**